# Processing sequences of variable length within a batch in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Suppose I have some data of shape `(?, 10)`.

That is, the features of the data are sequences of variable length and each element of the sequence is expressed by 10 numbers.

We want to feed this to a LSTM, so we prepare each batch to have length `(32, m, 10)`, where m is the max sequence length of the examples within the batch.

The examples within the batch of sequence length shorter than m are padded with zeroes.

Now, we want to feed this to a LSTM and we want the LSTM to stop updating the output on the padding inputs.

In Tensorflow, this would be done via the parameter `sequence_length` of its [`dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn).

How can I achieve the same effect in Keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [Masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) which will produce a *mask* that allows the LSTM to skip those padded values. From the documentation:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None, 10)))
model.add(LSTM(32))
```

The LSTM above will now skip timesteps where all the 10 features are 0 padded. **Note:** if you are returning sequences then the previous hidden state will be returned:

```
x = [2, 0, 1, 0] # for example
# will produce
y = [h1, h1, h2, h2] # so 0 pads are skipped
# but returning sequences repeats the last hidden state for masked values
```